# Look over my code for PDO and MVC

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysql, mvc, pdo

I'm building this website with PDO and Pattern MVC.  I'm currently working on the login page and would like to know if this structure is correct for MVC pattern.  I'd also like your opinions and advice on this.

For my **login view** I have:

```
<form action="test.php" name="loginform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Se connecter">
</form>
```

For my **login controller** I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $auth = new auth();
        $auth->setLogin($_POST['login']);
        $auth->setPassword(md5(sha1($_POST['password'])));
        if(($row = $auth->login('u_login,u_email,u_id_level', 'users', 'u_login', 'u_password'))){                 
            $_SESSION['back_office'] = array(
                'login' => $row->u_login,
                'email' => $row->u_email,
                'level' => $row->u_id_level
            );
        }else{
            message::showError('Compte non reconnu');
        }
    }else{
        message::showError('Veuillez remplir tous les champs');
    }
}
```

For my **login model** I have:

```
class auth{
    protected $rowUser;
    protected $login;
    protected $password;
    protected $email;

    public function setLogin($login){
        $this->login = $login;
    }
    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    /**
     * @return array $row
     */
    public function login($fields, $table, $col_login, $col_password){
        $query = Db::getInstance()->prepare('SELECT '.$fields.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$col_login.' = :login AND '.$col_password.' = :password');
        $query->bindValue(':login',$this->login,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':password',$this->password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $row = $query->fetch();
            return $row;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        $query->closeCursor();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor note: I'd reverse some conditions and use guard clauses to make the code flatten.

```
if(empty($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    message::showError('Veuillez remplir tous les champs');
    return;
}

$auth = new auth();
$auth->setLogin($_POST['login']);
$auth->setPassword(md5(sha1($_POST['password'])));
if(!($row = $auth->login('u_login,u_email,u_id_level', 'users', 'u_login', 'u_password'))){                 
    message::showError('Compte non reconnu');
    return;
}
$_SESSION['back_office'] = array(
    'login' => $row->u_login,
    'email' => $row->u_email,
    'level' => $row->u_id_level
);
```

(You might need to extract this out to a function.)

References:

- *Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler;
- [Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)

Answer (score 2):

A part of code in auth::login() of method you should move to other class, for example 'db'. Because you class auth has too much responsibility. For example if you want to have dynamic define fields in class auth:

Db class:

```
class db {
    public function getItem($table, $fields = '*', $conditions = array()) {
        // you code ...
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Your model:

```
class auth {
    private $table = 'users';
    private $fields = 'u_login, u_email, u_id_level';
    private $fieldLogin = 'u_login';
    private $fieldPassword = 'u_password';

    public function setTable($value) { $this->table = $value; }
    public function setFields($value) { $this->fields = $value; }
    public function setFieldLogin($value) { $this->fieldLogin = $value; }
    public function setFieldPassword($value) { $this->fieldPassword = $value; }

    public function login() {
        $db = new db();
        return $db->getItem($this->table, $this->fields, array(
            $this->fieldLogin => $this->login,
            $this->fieldPassword => $this->password
        ));
    }   
}
```

This code is more elastic and simpler will be change it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just about the security:

`md5(sha1());` is the worst security you can do.

Let's just say that I am a hacker that happens to come accross a database dump of your user table. I can now start cracking your user's passwords.

Because I am such a 'good' hacker I have multiple ways of going at your code.

There is the bruteforce way: simply trying all possibilities. But I don't think I need to explain that trying all possibilities is not that fast...

Then I can use dictionary atack, simply try all most used passwords and combinations of those passwords.

This greatly reduces the amount of time needed to crack a users password and is only held back by the time it takes to generate a hash. You use 2 hashes so it will take some time. Do that times the amount of passwords and maybe my grandson will have all passwords cracked.

However, I can use a rainbow table. Since you are using the exace same algorithm for all users I can create a database table with all calculated hashes in it. Then I perform a simple `SELECT password FROM rainbowtable WHERE hash = :theHachedHash;` BOOM!

But now the time creating a rainbow table is the one thing that is holding me back. Because there are still a lot of possibilities. But there is where **you** helped me out. You crate a `md5` hash of an `sha1` hash. Oh man, thank you!
I now know that I only need to check for md5 hashes of 20-string long strings to get the sha1 string. And then I only need a rainbow table for password to sha1 (google will help me there). So by hashing you password twice you have succesfully helped me crack your passwords by using 2 rainbow tables. 1 for md5 -> 20string long string (that one will take a couple of minutes to create on a cheap laptop) and one of the many rainbow tables for sha1 you can find in google.

But that is not is, you have not only choosen to fall for the trap of hashing a password twice, you are actually using hashing algorithms that are weak and have been cracked many years ago. So to say: your password hashing algorithm is a laugh and will only work against script kiddies, but they won't even get to the database in the first place...

So, as we saw above, with a technique called Rainbowtables I can easily hack your users password. You could upgrade the security by using a stronger hashing algorithm that takes more time to create.
But as computers get stronger, you would always have to upgrade your algorithm.

But don't cry! there is a solution. It's called SALT. Instead of somply passing a password into a hashing algorithm, we first append a unique random string to the password. Then we hash it in a strong algorithm.
Now the atacker will have to create a rainbow table for every user. Even is the users have the same passwords. `passwordRandomString1` has a different hash then `passwordRandomString2`

But now we have two things to secure, the unique SALT has to be absolutely random, so for instance `time()` will not suffice since it time based and that is not random. We could use the built in random generator of php. But this one uses time() to generate random numbers. So it is good enough for application logic, but not for security.

But lucky for us, some really smart people did all the work for us. We have some very nice libraries for all languages.
[pkbf2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) being one of them with a [native implementation](http://be1.php.net/hash-pbkdf2). Or even better [crypt](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) using the blowfish algorithm.